# The search option isanswered:no shows answered questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Searching with: [sdl] isanswered:no shows answered questions.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Stack Overflow definition for unanswered is

> no **upvoted** answers.

So your search will return questions that have answers if their score is less than 1.

The definition is designed to return questions that might need a better answer as well as questions that have no answer.

If you think any of the answers help then consider upvoting them which will remove them from the search.